# Finding nodes with QGIS

Tags: qgis, density

As part of work in statistical mapping for school, I need to use QGIS to find the spatial extent of commercial nodes.  A node is defined for this exercise as a zone of 75m in diameter where the density of shops is greater than or equal to 5.

The problem is less one of finding the spatial extent of the nodes than to find and map the nodes themselves.  To find the nodes, I have 5 shapefiles, each corresponding to a type of commerce in Villeurbanne (the study area for this exercise).  I have merged these five shapefiles into a single one, in the hope of simplifying my life (but perhaps that's a mistake...). I therefore have available a vector file where 2018 points represent the various shops in Villeurbanne.

What I would like to do is to analyze a circle of 75m in diameter (or a radius of 37.5m) around each point representing a shop, in order to know how many shops are found in this circle.  I don't know whether it's possible with vector software... I know that a similar operation exists in raster software like ILWIS for analyzing data in continuous grids, because I have done that before, but I have to work in QGIS for this exercise.

Once the shops have been found within a 75m diameter zone, I will have to be able to create the regions of intersection, which would give me the nodes.

I'm a beginner with QGIS, an application that I have used only once or twice last year by following instructions, but this year no instructions are indicated.

Answer (score 10):

Here is one method

- First make sure you re-project your shapefile into a projected CRS with meters as units. Let's say this file is named 'points'

[image]
 - Next use Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Buffer. Use 37.5 as the buffer distance. Call the buffer layer as 'buffer'.

[image]

- Then use Vector -> Analysis Tools -> Point in Polygon. Use 'point' as input point layer and 'buffer' as input polygon layer. This will count how many points from your original shapefile fall within each of the buffered polygon. PNTCNT field will have the counts.
  [image]
- Now select the polygons where PNTCNT >= 5
  [image]
- Then use Vector -> Geometry tools -> Polygon Centroids on the selection to get the original point locations. You can also just use the Attribute Table to identify ids of the original points.